# CreateFileW is failing because of invalid path

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am trying to create a file with GENERIC_WRITE permission with a path entered by the user.

To get user input, I am using `fwgets` function.

```
VOID DoCreateFile() {
    SIZE_T sAlloc = sizeof(WCHAR) * (MAX_WPATH + 1); // allocation size

    // allocating space and checking if actually allocated
    LPWSTR lpPath = (LPWSTR)malloc(sAlloc);
    LPWSTR lpContent = (LPWSTR)malloc(sAlloc);
    if (lpPath == NULL || lpContent == NULL) {
        PrintLastError(L"malloc()", TRUE);
    }

    wprintf(L"Enter path of file: ");
    fgetws(lpPath, sAlloc, stdin); // read the contents of stdin with space

    wprintf(L"Enter content (max 256 chars): ");
    fgetws(lpContent, sAlloc, stdin);
    
    /*
        Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew
    */
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(lpPath, // path of file
        GENERIC_WRITE, // creating file with write permission
        FILE_SHARE_READ, // allow other process to open file for reading
        NULL, // disallow handle inheritance
        CREATE_ALWAYS, // overwrite file if exists, otherwise create a new one
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, // do not set any file attributes
        NULL // not using any file template
        );
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        PrintLastError(L"CreateFileW()", TRUE);
    }


    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

Error message printed by PrintLastError function: **CreateFileW() Failed! The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**

The input I have entered on the console is

```
Enter path of file: c:\file.txt
Enter content (max 256 chars): s
```

I have also tried file path `\\.\C:\file.txt`.

FYI, when I replace `lpPath` with a wide string literal `L"C:\\Files.txt"`, the function succeeds.

Comment: Please read more about [`fgetws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetws), especially what it does with the newline.

Comment: Also, this code is leaking the memory it allocates.

Comment: It is reading [newline](https://i.imgur.com/kiGsSC6.png)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is `\n` valid ending character for CreateFileW?

Comment: @tbhaxor I doubt its a valid character *anywhere* in a filename.

Comment: Use a debugger to look at the actual contents of `lpPath`. What is the actual string in it? And check what `fgetws` *returns* to make sure it succeeds.